# Why Are Traditional Aimbots not Packet Based

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, game-engine

I know that most aimbots work by detouring certain functions in memory in order to get access to certain structures, variables, even functions themselves. But the problem with this is there are many cheat detection methods for scanning memory and finding such software. Wouldn't it be easier to reverse engineer the packets sent by the game containing player data and modifying those before they are sent out? Or is it just easier  to reverse the cheat detection methods and nullify(?) those?

Comment: What if the application used some form of encryption on the outgoing packets?

Comment: I know that some anti-cheat engines checks for packet sniffers too, which is why running some programs(like fiddle) in the background can get you flagged.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins I would assume that they would be scanning for known packet sniffers, not something you wrote yourself.

Comment: @mfontanini I don't have much experience with game network protocols. Is it fairly common for there to be encryption on the game data?

Comment: @Adam that's entirely possible, I have no idea how you'd general scan for packet sniffers without doing system sweeps.

Comment: @Adam I don't usually have a look at game network protocols, but when I do, packets are encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

One packet can do many things. You get a packet saying player was hit by an explosion. This might:

- Change the players health
- Change the players position
- Change the players velocity
- Change the players orientation

all at once. You could intercept the packet, update all these yourself by reverse engineering what each packet does and how it does it, and basically simulate your own model of the game.

Or you can let the game do it for you and just read the values it generates.

Comment: I would certainly hope there would be checking on the server side for clients doing things such as editing there health.

Comment: @Adam: Hm? Of course games may add encryption and detect packet sniffers, if that's what you mean. I was hoping to address your conjecture that it would be easier to sniff packets than game values.

Comment: No I mean if a player gets hit by a rocket (for example) the client should return to the server that it has <100 health. I would think that if the server is using a known algorithm to encrypt packets, it wouldn't be that hard to decrypt them.

Comment: @Adam: The server is the one that tells the client he was hit by the rocket, it already knows the entire state of the game. This is where lag comes in: is your local simulation accurate? When the server sends you the "real" world state, how closely does the client match? When it doesn't, you see snapping and other effects of lag.